# Checking if an Object is null at the same time as a value of one of it's fields

Tags: java

Which of these would be correct?

```
if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing){}

if(dialog.isShowing && dialog != null){}

if(dialog != null){
   if(dialog.isShowing){}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first and third ones are both OK to use because they won't process past the null check. The second one can result in a `NullPointerException` because it's referencing `dialog` before you've checked if it's null.

Comment: Okay, so the first expression is evaluated first... and if it fails the second will not be evaluated, correct?

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what I needed to confirm (the order they're evaluated... I'm quite aware of the NullPointerException that would occur if the second expression were evaluated first). Thanks again.

Comment: @Maximus: It is also true for `||` expressions. If the left predicate is `true` then the right predicate is never evaluated. It's called [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 5):

The && operator in Java will stop evaluating (from left to right) as soon as it encounters a false.  Therefore in

```
if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing){}
```

dialog.isShowing() will not be called if the dialog is null and is therefore "safe" to use.

This:

```
if(dialog != null){
   if(dialog.isShowing){}
}
```

will work as well, but generally nesting if-statements like this is avoided as it decreases readability.

Answer (score 2):

Even though everything has been answered, for the sake of completeness:
The way Java evaluates conditional clauses is called [Short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This means that once the result of the condition is asserted, further clauses will not be evaluated.

Edit: My statement is not completely true actually. Java uses Short circuit evaluation when using || and && (which is the standard what every programmer uses, thus my statement in the first place), but you may force Java to evaluate all statements by using & and |

Comment: Thanks for this, the link was helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operator is called a short circuit operator.  This means once the result is known. i.e., `false && x` is always `false` it doesn't evaluate the remaining expressions.

A variation on this is using the `||` short circuit, OR operation, like:

```
if(text == null || text.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's shortcut logic. When first expression is false, Java will not check second expression, because whole expression is false definity.

- First case is best practice.
- Second case is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You may use try and catch if you want to use the second one otherwise the first and the third one are correct.